# Is there a way to get the items written from an ItemWriterListener in Spring Batch for further use downstream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to get the items stored in my ItemWriterListener into the JobExecutionListener for retrieval in downstream processing.  I implemented both the ItemWriterListener and StepExecutionListener interfaces but the @AfterStep is not invoked.

```java
           @Bean("updateProductDetailsStep")
           public Step updateProductDetailsStep(){
               return stepBuilderFactory.get("UpdateStep")
                 .<Product, Product>chunk(chunkSize)
                 .reader(productStreamingReader)
                 .processor(productItemProcessor)
                 .writer(productsUpdateWriter)
                 .listener((ItemWriterListener)productItemWriterListener) // Disambiguate
                 .build();
    }
```

At the //Disambiguate, I add a cast to differentiate between Listener interfaces since I implement StepExecutionListener and ItemWriterListener. Can this be achieved and how?

Comment: Not sure why you would need that? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve without referring to spring batch? It feels like too much processing is being done in a single step, while it could be split into different steps.

Comment: I am attempting to use some data retrieved in query from some upstream processes i.e. all the Product data read from the query.  I want to combine that data   with Products whose product data was found when adding their Product details further in my processing. The goal is ton produce a summary of all products that were read and whether product details were found for them.  I have solved the problem any but thanks for asking. I would interested in finding out what your thoughts are on your method how to solve this need

Comment: The driving query pattern might be helpful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders. The idea is to read products in the reader and enrich them in the processor. This works well for small/medium datasets, but does not perform well for large datasets due to the additional query in the processor to fetch the details of the current item.